# En anglais dans le texte

Tags: expressions

Je cherche une expression pour désigner un mot que l'on utilise tel quel, directement en anglais sans traduction. J'ai en tête un équivalent de "en français dans le texte", utilisé quand on traduit un texte non-français et qu'un des mots était déjà en français dans le texte initial. Ici ça ne s'applique pas vraiment mais je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai une intuition d'une expression qui ressemble.

Exemple :

*(c'est qu'un exemple, pas besoin d'être d'accord ou non pour le sens de ces phrases)*

> Pour ce genre de chose, on a pas vraiment de mot. En général, on parle juste de "craving", *en anglais dans le texte*.

Je cherche l'expression qui dit que le terme précédent est utilisé tel quel, dans sa langue d'origine. Surtout quand on a une répétition, c'est un peu étrange de ne rien mettre.

> Pour "craving", je vois pas d'équivalent, il va falloir soit te contenter d'expressions comme "envie irrésistible", soit utiliser "craving", <*directement en anglais*>.

---

Suggestions :

- "*En anglais*" est ambigu, si je dis "*on dit <mot> en anglais*" on va comprendre "*quand on parle en anglais*" (i.e. "*vélo on dit bicycle en anglais*")
- *Verbatim* veut dire "tel quel, à l'identique". Il est il me semble assez usité en anglais mais moins en français, et de ce que je vois il est plutôt utilisé dans le contexte de recopie parfaite de texte que d'usage de mot sans traduction.
- *Texto* est similaire mais familier et ne correspond pas tout à fait non plus, bien qu'il ait le sens de "tel quel, littéralement", il a une connotation de "franchement, brutalement, sans filtre".
- *Tel quel* pourrait convenir, il manque un peu le concept de traduction mais c'est probablement le meilleur candidat que j'ai pu trouver.
- un terme signifiant "*sans traduction*" ?

Est-ce qu'il existe une expression à côté duquel je suis passé ? Quel mot utiliseriez-vous ?

Comment: On utilise parfois l'expression « terme non traduit » en note de bas de page quand on veut laisser le mot dans sa langue originale parce que le traduire introduirait un faux-sens face à un concept très marqué (juridique, politique...), éventuellement, si le contexte n'est pas clair, on ajoute (du [langue]) mais je ne suis pas sûr que c'est ce que tu cherches.

Comment: Un emprunt lexical non adapté ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emprunt_(linguistique)# https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23787/les-emprunts-a-langlais/emprunts-integraux/quest-ce-quun-emprunt-integral

Comment: Chatgpt propose in extenso :
Pour "craving", je vois pas d'équivalent, il va falloir soit te contenter d'expressions comme "envie irrésistible", soit utiliser "craving", in extenso. Je ne donne pas ça comme réponse et j'hésite, parce que c'est plutôt un terme d'origing juridique pas avec ce sens.

Comment: In extenso se dit plus pour un texte qu'un mot, non ?

Comment: on peut préciser "terme intraduisible en français" pour expliquer pourquoi on le garde tel quel.

Comment: .. soit simplement conserver __l'anglicisme__ *craving* / soit simplement conserver *craving* __(sic)__ ?

Answer (score 2):

À l'écrit, l'usage consiste à mettre en italiques les mots étrangers. Ce doit suffire à faire comprendre sa reprise à l'identique.

> Pour *craving*, je vois pas d'équivalent. Il va falloir soit te contenter d'expressions comme « envie irrésistible », soit simplement conserver *craving* / soit garder l'anglais *craving*.

S'il faut vraiment une expression, celle que tu as déjà fournie, la formule « en anglais dans le texte » est appropriée bien qu'un peu longue.

Comment: Ou même: "soit garder le mot anglais ", "soit laisser l'anglicisme", évitant la répétition.

Comment: La série des *Carnets du major Thompson* de P. Daninos contient toutes sortes de solutions éditoriales au pb., certaines ouvertement facétieuses.